# SQL: how to select IDs according to a condition?

Tags: sql

I just started to program in SQL and I have a bit of a problem (n.b., I am working of a tabl that come from a game). My table is something like this, where ID refers to a single person, H to a certain hour of playing and IF to a certain condition:

```
ID  H  IF

01  1  0
01  2  0
01  3  0
02  1  0
02  2  1
03  1  0
03  2  1
03  3  0
03  4  1
```

In this case player 01 played for three hours, player 02 for two hours and player 03 for four hours. In each of these hours they may or may have not performed an action. If they did, a 1 appears in the IF column.

Now, my doubt is: how can I query so that I have a table with only the ID of the people who never performed the action? I do not want to rule out only the row with IF = 1, I want to rule out all the row with that ID. In this case it should become:

```
01  1  0
01  2  0
01  3  0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
select *
from table
where Id not in (select Id from table where IF = 1)
```

Comment: I receive the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'" if I try to execute that query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID FROM Table GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(IF)=0
```

Comment: This query does not Output what the questioner wanted. According to the sample result he wants a table with ID, H and IF.

Comment: From the question: `how can I query so that I have a table with only the ID of the people who never performed the action?`. So it is up for interpretation I think. This is just another way to do it. It can also be wrapped in another query to get all the three fields.